# Unable to get data from JSON in Applescript

Tags: json, applescript

So I'm able to get the values from one api but I'm unable to get the second value, which is a currency conversion rate (from an entirely different source). I've pasted my code below, any help would be much appreciated.

```
set json to (do shell script "curl https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/ticker/xrpusd")

tell application "JSON Helper"
    set result to read JSON from json
    set price to |last| of result as number
end tell

set json to (do shell script "curl https://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=INR")

tell application "JSON Helper"
    set result to read JSON from json
    set inr to |INR| of result as number
end tell

set result_string to "₹" & price * inr & ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I open the second URL in a browser, here’s the JSON that gets returned (formatted for easier reading):

```
{"base":"EUR",
 "date":"2018-02-05",
 "rates":{
     "INR":79.744
     }
}
```

The `INR` value is inside the `rates` value.  Therefore, you need to reference it like so:

```
    set inr to (INR of rates of result) as number
```

I don’t see any reason to enclose `INR` inside vertical bars, as there’s no conflicting AppleScript commands or variables with that name.  You can even get away with defining `inr` as a user-defined variable, and AppleScript will be able to distinguish when you’re referencing that from when your referencing `INR of rates`.

However, `result` is a pre-defined AppleScript property, so I would avoid using this in the way that you have.  What you can do is change this line:

```
    set result to read JSON from json
```

to this:

```
    read JSON from json
```

and keep the subsequent line as it is (with my suggested correction from above).  Now you’ll be using the AppleScript `result` property correctly.

Comment: BTW The AppleScript `result` is a globally available property, not a variable.

Comment: @user3439894 The [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW8) says _"You can assign the result of a command to a variable you define, or access it through the predefined AppleScript_ `result` _variable."_  Is this an error ?

Comment: "AppleScript stores the result in the globally available property `result`, described in [AppleScript Constant](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW38).

Comment: "`result` When a statement is executed, AppleScript stores the resulting value, if any, in the predefined property `result`. The value remains there until another statement is executed that generates a value. Until a statement that yields a result is executed, the value of `result` is undefined. You can examine the result in Script Editor by looking in the Result pane of the script window."

Comment: @user3439894 How does one reconcile the two pieces of evidence which appear to hold equal value ?

Comment: The use of "result variable" under Commands Overview at the link you referenced is categorically wrong and to be considered a typo. Variables and Properties differ and AppleScript's `result` **is** a globally defined property not a variable!

Comment: @user3439894 That would have been a more suitable answer to my first reply.  I’m not being flippant when I say I find this a really interesting subject of discussion.  Without implying any doubt to what you’re saying (I respect your knowledge and expertise here), I feel there’s a missing link in the chain of knowledge that allows you to get from the possibility that `result` is either a variable or a property to the assertion that it is definitively the latter.  *Script Editor* also refers to `result` as a variable.  Also, I wonder what value the distinction has in this case.

Comment: But I shalln’t continue to feed my academic curiosities in the comments section.  If you have the patience for a dialectic on this matter, feel free to start a chat.  If not, I’m happy to leave it alone and just accept it as something I don’t fully understand yet.

Comment: I can't today as I'm heading out the KSC for the launch of the Falcon Heavy later today, another time though.